# How create a string of distinct values from an Array (Including additional chars)

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have a simple question for the LINQ experts.
I want create a single string based in an Array:

```
return String.Join(",", (from string val 
     in arrayValues
     select new { value = "%" + val.ToString() + "%" })
     .Distinct().ToArray());
```

This code give an error, but I cannot found the way how fix the issue.

Example; I want to send `{"1","2","3","4"}` and my expected result should be something like that: `"%1%,%2%,%3%,%4%"`

Any help will be welcome!

Comment: Are you going to make us guess what the error is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from your example why you need `Distinct` but you can do:

```
return string.Join(",", arrayValues.Distinct().Select(s => "%" + s + "%"));
```

or

```
var values = from val in arrayValues.Distinct() select "%" + val + "%";
return string.Join(",", values);
```

Comment: I still feel very familiar with the VB.NET. I not saw this workaround in C#.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use:

```
return String.Join(",", arrayValues.Distinct().Select(v => "%" + v + "%"));
```

If you always will have at least one element, you could also use:

```
return "%" + string.Join("%,%", arrayValues.Distinct()) + "%";
```